# Python API response - GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm calling google API from python requests, I'm able to get response from the API also able to extract status code if request is failing like 404. But how do I get success response as 200? I do not see any attribute with that status.

For example:

```
request = service.disks().get(project=project, zone=zone, disk=disk).execute()
```

`response.status` or `response.status_code` does not help.

Comment: Are you really checking `response.status` or it was a typo and you meant to say `request.status`? Can you post a more complete code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `service.disks().get(project=project, zone=zone, disk=disk).execute()` returns the dictionary.

Check the `request['status']`, it will return `READY`.

[Document reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/get?hl=en-GB)